# Unhide a tooltip when hovering on another one

Tags: jquery, css, hover, tooltip

I got a Jquery query. It may be super simple for some of the jquery gurus here. So I have these list of services on the left and a tooltip icon on the right. On hovering, it displays info related to the particular service. I manage to get the tooltip from another Stackoverflow post. But my client wants the first tooltip to hover on page load. I manage to get that as well from Stackoverflow.

Although where I am stuck at is, how to hide the first tooltip when someone hovers on the other ones.

**I got this code to display tooltip on hover**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

**And I got this code to display the first one on page load**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle=tooltip-active]').tooltip({trigger: 'manual'}).tooltip('show');
});
```

Kindly please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try destroying the tooltip on `mouseenter` and re-enabling it on `mouseleave` events of the other tooltips:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('[data-toggle=tooltip]').hover(function() {
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip-active]').tooltip('destroy'); 
    }, function() {
        $('[data-toggle=tooltip-active]').tooltip({trigger: 'hover'}); 
    });

});
```

Assuming you're using [Bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Comment: Hey David... that worked great but then when I hover back on the first one, it doesn't show the tooltip.. haha.. :)
I need to just hide it not destroy. I mean I want it to hide temporarily unless hovered on it again.

Comment: @JesseAlex Slightly altered my answer. Give it a try

Comment: Hey David, can you please help me with this post too? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535860/jquery-script-doesnt-work-right-on-safari